# Generate WSDL from Java Web Service in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, google-app-engine, wsdl

I have a GAE web service with a few GETs and POSTs, I am required to have a WSDL of the web service.

I have found several pages and posts about generating a web service from WSDL but how would I generate a WSDL from an already created web service? I was told this is possible with only a few clicks in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the WebService producer gives you the WSDL.  Most web services you are able to get to the WSDL by postfixing ?WSDL to the URL.  Keep in mind that, some web service providers disable this feature.

That is if you have a web service here

```
http://hostname:1234/webservice
```

you can use

```
http://hostname:1234/webservice?wdsl
```

to retrieve the WSDL